# When using Backburner for beanstalk how do I start workers while in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beanstalkd

I've read though the [Backburner Tutorial](https://github.com/nesquena/backburner/wiki/Backburner-Tutorial) but it kind of glosses over what workers are exactly, and it seems as though god is used for production environments, but all the other examples just show Backburner.work being used, which doesn't process asynchronously. So I can't figure how to do process jobs in my queue while I'm using WEBrick in development mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will update the tutorial but the simplest way to process tasks is to just use the rake task:

```
rake backburner:work
```

This will process tasks as they come in right in your console. If you have dynamic queues or just want to process one queue you can specify the queues here:

```
QUEUES=newsletter-sender,push-message rake backburner:work
```

That should work in development.

Comment: Tutorial has been updated, let me know if that clears it up for future developers :) or if I can add anything else to it.

Comment: `Don't know how to build task 'backburner:work'` ʘ⁔ʘ

Comment: I finally figured it out: You need to `require 'backburner/tasks'` in your Rakefile!